# category.php с постами нескольких категорий

Tags: wordpress

Вопрос по Wordpress.

Есть 4 категории постов: news, events, video, forum. Каждая категория имеет ещё 4 категории: design, security, it, ip.

Посты добавляют пользователи через форму прямо на главной странице (не в админке, плагин "User Submitted Posts").

При добавлении поста нужно обязательно выбрать одну из первых четырёх категорий и одну из вторых четырёх категорий (и первый дополнительный вопрос: как это сделать; сейчас можно выбрать только одну категорию из выпадающего списка). То есть каждый пост у нас должен иметь две категории.

Вопрос следующий: как добавить ссылку (как она будет выглядеть) на страницу category.php с постами, относящимися к двум категориям сразу (news и design, например)? И как на этой странице получить эти две категории вне цикла?

p.s. Вторые четыре категории нельзя сделать подкатегориями, как я понимаю, так как каждая категория должна иметь уникальное имя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В админке создаете страницу со слагом, например, `filter`. В папке темы создаете файл `page-filter.php` (то есть к слагу слева добавляете `page-`). В этот файл вставляете код:

```
<?php
$cat1 = 1;
$cat2 = 26;
$args = array( 'category' => "{$cat1}, {$cat2}");
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
    if (in_category($cat1, $post) && in_category($cat2, $post)) {
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

В коде как раз указываете те две категории, которые надо вывести.

Comment: Ответ надо понимать как общую идею, вопросы передачи параметров на эту страницу, интерфейса по выбору параметров (имен категорий) я предоставляю вам решить самому.

Comment: Это вариант, но совсем не удобный. Тогда надо создать 16 страниц, правильно я понимаю? Именно так и было у меня реализовано по сей день, но проблема в том, что категорий у меня гораздо больше. 4 категории я взял для примера, чтоб проще было понять. Эти страницы все идентичны, за исключением того, какие посты выводятся и какой пункт меню подсвечен, поэтому хотелось бы это организовать одним файлом category.php и там всё на условиях выводить.

Comment: Это идея. Нормальный программист не станет создавать 4 в 4 степени страниц. Он передаст параметры вместо '1,5'.

Comment: В каком файле передаст параметры вместо '1,5'. В category.php? Так я с удовольствием их и передал бы, но мне для начала надо понять: какой URL имеет страница с двумя категориями news и design, потому что сейчас я могу перейти и по ссылке "/news/", и по "/design/", и по "/news/design/", и наоборот. И везде get_the_category() не выводит ничего, только single_cat_title() работает.

Comment: Я все написал про слаг.

Comment: Вы поймите, здесь не бесплатный freelance. Вы хотите, чтобы я за вас всю задачу сделал? У меня нет ни времени, ни желания. Я вам дал направление, достаточно профессиональное. Дерзайте.

Comment: Никто Вас не просит выполнять за меня задачу. Я задаю конкретные вопросы. Вы бы могли меня поправить. Я отмечу вопрос решённым, спасибо: по Вашей наводке создал страницу page-filter.php и в ссылках на неё (в меню) я передаю параметры (типа /filter?cat1=news&cat2=design). Но так цикл будет выдавать все страницы, которые относятся к первой рубрике, и все страницы, которые относятся ко второй рубрике, а мне нужно, чтобы он выводил только те страницы, которые относятся к обеим рубрикам одновременно. + у меня цикл в виде sql-запроса. У меня Ваш пример так звучит: WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (1,5)

Comment: Да, я пропустил в вашем вопросе, что вам надо одновременно две. Исправил ответ, оттестировал на test.kagg.eu/filter/ Код в файле filter.php идентичен тому, что в ответе, а посмотреть записи и их принадлежность к категориям можно тут: http://test.kagg.eu/blog/